# change string format in php by add \n so that it works in a js file that reads csv

Tags: javascript, php, str-replace

this is the string I have :

```
#jazzy
# Audience Overview
2014-09-03,28
2014-09-04,17
2014-09-05,20
2014-09-06,3204
2014-09-07,1717
2014-09-08,737
2014-09-09,160
2014-09-10,89
2014-09-11,85
2014-09-12,21
```

I need it in this format:

```
\n#jazzy\n# Audience Overview\nDay,Visits\n3/9/14,9691\n1/10/14,35403\n2/10/14,35403\n
```

I have tried str_replace it didn't work. when I echo the value I need it to be the second one. any help please

Comment: `\n` isn't an actual sequence of characters, it's just how we represent a newline in a string literal. Your string already has newlines, you don't need to do anything to it.

Comment: it doesn't work .. I am using highcharts to show the data and its returned with echo $string; it says token illegal. that exact string i pasted it on here. If instead i put static values in data data: { csv: '\n#Tempo\n# Audience Overview\nDay,Visits\n3/9/14,9691\n1/10/14,35403\n2/10/14,35403\n'} this works

Comment: `$str=preg_replace(array("/[\n\r]/", "[\r]"),"\\n",str_replace('-', '/', $str));`? Although I still don't understand why you would want this to be the production of that `#jazzy\n\n# Audience Overview\n\n2014/09/03,28\n\n2014/09/04,17\n\n2014/09/05,20\n\n2014/09/06,3204\n\n2014/09/07,1717\n\n2014/09/08,737\n\n2014/09/09,160\n\n2014/09/10,89\n\n2014/09/11,85\n\n2014/09/12,21`

Comment: what are you trying to feed into highcharts anyway? is this a line graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to turn a PHP literal into a Javascript literal, use `json_encode`:

```
var csv = <?php echo json_encode($string); ?>;
```

This will take care of any necessary encoding, including translating newlines to literal `\n`.